# Has there been a big uptake of merchants accepting Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, merchants

With Bitcoin Cash still relatively new (August 2017), are there any statistics available on the percentage of merchants who previously accepted Bitcoin, that now also accept Bitcoin Cash, or that switched over to accepting Bitcoin Cash instead of Bitcoin?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the community created webpage: https://acceptbitcoin.cash/

If you are looking at the percentage of merchants who previously accepted Bitcoin, that now also accept Bitcoin Cash, there is a statement that says that 131 out of 1053 websites listed support Bitcoin Cash.